# JSONBuilder in Grails console

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm trying to use the Groovy JSONBuilder in the Grails (2.0.0.M2) console. When I execute the following

```
import grails.web.JSONBuilder                

def builder = new JSONBuilder()

def result = builder.build {
    foo = 'bar'    
}

result.toString()
```

I get the error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object 'bar' with class 'java.lang.String' to class
>   'grails.converters.JSON'
>
> at grails.web.JSONBuilder.build(JSONBuilder.groovy:39)

The builder seems to work fine in the app itself. Is there a reason why it doesn't work in the console?

Answer (score 0):

While i was working with JSONBuilder, i faced similar problems, then i decide to not use JSONBuilder. If it is not necessary for you, you can change your builder.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*; 
import grails.converters.JSON;             

def result =[:]
result.foo='bar'

println result as JSON
```

it's result will be same.

Comment: My real example is much more complicated and cannot easily be accomplished using a Map

Comment: i have 4 level JSON and i can use it. i haven't faced any problem about it.